# How to do optimization in C. Is there any need of volatile keyword if i set optimization level to none(-0)

Tags: c, optimization, volatile

I am not understanding a simple thing, if we set optimization level to none(means don't optimize) then is there necessary to use volatile keyword in C.

Comment: whether it is necessary to use `volatile` or not, depends on what you're supposed to do with your variable

Comment: Setting optimization level to 0 guarantees precisely nothing.

Comment: Suppose you didn't need `volatile` with optimization off. Would you really want to write your code in such a way that bugs only show up when optimization is on?

Answer (score 4):

Turning off optimization does not mean broken code will start working. Anything that would need to be volatile with optimization on must be volatile with optimization off. For example, without a volatile modifier, access to the variable might be cached in a register instead of properly interfacing with whatever it's supposed to interface with.

Comment: Note that `volatile` only disables compiler optimizations -- the CPU may still reorder loads and stores and show an inconsistent state to other CPUs. You need memory barriers (or similar) to prevent the CPU from reordering things.

Comment: which makes "For example, without a volatile modifier, access to the variable might hit cache instead of properly interfacing with whatever it's supposed to interface with." incorrect.

Comment: @auselen: Well, yes and no. Volatile is intended for interfacing with hardware -- it basically causes loads or stores to a memory location to be considered "observable behavior" from the compiler's prospective. If you're interfacing with a machine that uses memory mapping for IO, for example, then volatile is entirely appropriate, and user2357112's statement would be correct. If, however, you are attempting to synchronize access to data across multiple CPUs on the same machine, then volatile is inappropriate.

Comment: @auselen (Of course, technically his statement is correct -- *with or * without volatile access to the variable might hit cache) :)

Comment: @BillyONeal I was thinking like; if you want to access a memory address then that address needs to be not cachable (strongly ordered or device memory on ARM for example) at HW and OS level. Compiler wouldn't help you to skip caches just because you use volatile on modern+advanced HW.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Memory-mapped IO was the case I was thinking of, but I haven't actually used it, only read about it. It's not clear to me whether you're saying that memory-mapped I/O does or doesn't need to be declared volatile. I think you're trying to say that you need to do additional things besides declaring it volatile, but you still need to declare it volatile. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: What volatile mostly does is tell the compiler that it can't make assumptions about the value of a volatile object from one read or write to the next. Memory mapped IO is an example of a case where this is important - you don't want the compiler to do things like eliminate two writes of the same value to the same address because that might mean something specific when doing memory mapped IO. The C++ standard doesn't say anything about the CPU cache and any additional semantics that volatile may have in a particular implementation are implementation defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a nice question but answer is probably it is completely up to the compiler.

Assuming you want to use `volatile` to not reorder volatile reads / writes and `-O0` to keep program order.

For example [GCC doc states](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

> -fno-toplevel-reorder
>
> Do not reorder top-level functions, variables, and asm statements.
>   **Output them in the same order that they appear in the input file.** When
>   this option is used, unreferenced static variables are not removed.
>   This option is intended to support existing code that relies on a
>   particular ordering. For new code, it is better to use attributes when
>   possible.
>
> **Enabled at level -O0.** When disabled explicitly, it also implies -fno-section-anchors, which is otherwise enabled at -O0 on some targets.

Of course correct way is still to use [volatile](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Volatiles.html) properly rather than relying on program order and `-O0` flag.

There is also no guarantee that even in `-O0` compiler might not do some optimizations.

Comment: That setting controls in what order things get emitted into the file, but does not prevent reordering of operations against given pieces of data. Saying that position of data on the stack or the position of functions in a binary don't change doesn't say anything about whether operations against that data within a function are reordered or not.

Comment: @BillyONeal can you clarify that? do you mean from HW perspective? or compiler could just change order of arithmetics, etc?

Comment: Yes. For example, if your function has something like `x * y + a * b`, the compiler may calculate `x * y` first, then `a * b` second, or `a * b` first, and `x * y` second, depending on what it thinks is optimal.

Comment: @BillyONeal You are right but I would guess there must be another flag to avoid that which is enabled at -O0 :)

Comment: I'm not sure how it could be avoided. Code that depends on the execution order there exhibits undefined behavior -- the standard literally does not define an ordering here. See 1.9 [intro.execution]/15: `evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual
expressions are unsequenced`